# Git push --set-upstream issue

Tags: git, git-bash

the branch `refs/remotes/origin/feature/US12376` was pushed to `origin` but times before it asked:

```
Your branch is based on 'origin/feature/US12376', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
```

so I used `git branch --unset-upstream` (passed successfully).

### Continue working in it

After commit I try `git push --set-upstream origin feature/US12376` but got error:

```
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/US12376': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/US12376': 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/US12376/patchFix' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/US12376'
```

remote branch `refs/remotes/origin/feature/US12376/patchFix` was deleted.

Comment: Could it be you still have a reference to it locally. Try `git remote prune origin`

Comment: @crea1 yea, its really helps, thanks. Add answer please :)

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local git repository still has a reference to `refs/remotes/origin/feature/US12376/patchFix`, even though it has been deleted remotely.

To remove those references you can run

```
git remote prune origin
```